# Accord de l'adjectif standard

Tags: adjectifs, accord

On lit dans un ouvrage sur LaTeX :

> En tout cas pour les versions TeX/LaTeX les plus **courantes** et
>   généralement les plus **standard**.

Je me demande pourquoi il n'y pas d'accord pour le second adjectif. Est-ce une faute de frappe ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Courant*** est ici un adjectif qui s'accorde normalement en genre et en nombre.

***[Standard](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/standard/1)*** est un mot anglais provenant du français ***[étendard](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9tendard)*** qui peut être un substantif ou un adjectif. L'accord ne se faisait pas tant que l'adjectif gardait sa nature étrangère, puisqu'il n'y a pas d'accord des adjectifs en anglais.

On peut aussi voir *standard* comme un substantif adjectivé, comme le sont aussi certains noms de couleurs où l'accord ne se fait traditionnellement pas non plus : *les voitures marron*.

Depuis, l'adjectif s'est francisé et l'accord pluriel est devenu possible mais  toujours optionnel (*les plus **standards***).

En revanche, probablement parce qu'il entraîne un changement de prononciation, l'accord au féminin ne se fait jamais (*les plus <s>**standardes**</s>*).

Source: http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1394

Comment: !!! Merci. Où peut-on trouver plus de renseignements ?

Comment: J'ai ajusté ma réponse et ajouté une source.

Comment: Merci encore. Existent-ils d'autres adjectifs comme standard (hormis les adjectifs de couleur comme marron) ? Est-il mieux d'utiliser le synonyme (plus francisés) normalisé ?

Comment: Il y en a plein, par exemple *témoin*. On peut utiliser *les plus standard*, le sens est légèrement différent de *les plus standardisées*, sinon *les plus proches du standard*.